# How does the programmatic creation of a script element node force a browser to treat the <script> element asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am reading a book DOM Enlightenment and there's a section which says

> I programmatically create the `<script>` element node and then append it
>   to the `<body>` element which forces the browser to treat the `<script>`
>   element asynchronously.

How does this force the browser?

Comment: That's just what browsers do. If you think about it, loading the script *synchronously* would be very problematic as processing that code could (probably would) alter the global environment, the DOM, and many other things that the code doing the appending might not expect.

Comment: Thanks @pointy, I know it's very problematic to process the synchronous code. But why the code doing the appending might not expect the altered global environment? Can you please give some example? Just trying to understand better. Thank you.